# Bootstrap carousel images not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Getting crazy :D Been stuck for three days.

I am trying to put a carousel in my page, I am loading the images located in my machine, each one having a size of 1200*480.
When I test it the images are not shown.
This is the code:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Kurt Angle</h1>
  <p>Olympic Gold Medalist, World Champion, Hall of Famer, Living Legend</p></div>

<!--CAROUSEL BEGINES-->
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="carousel slide"
       data ride="carousel"
       id="carousel">

    <!--indicators--->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!--wrapper of the images(itmes)--->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="Pictures/angle_olympics_croppedxcf.jpg" alt="slide1">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="file:///home/davide/Pictures/angle%20cropped%202.jpg"
             alt="slide2">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="file:///home/davide/Pictures/kurt_angle_cropped_3.jpg"
             alt="slide3">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--now let's put right and left control-->
    <a class="left carousel-control" 
       href="#carousel" 
       role="button" 
       data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>

CSS:
.jumbotron{
  background-color: #241f14 !important;
  color: #ffffff;
  }

.carousel .item{
  height: 100%;

}
```

[Codepen page](https://codepen.io/davide2894/pen/jByzKy?editors=1100)

Please could you help me?

Comment: you have to post what you have tried.

Comment: Hi Davide... Can you please give path where your images located? and where's your slider loaded?

Comment: They are located in my computer, what do you mean with the second question?

Comment: I guess the problem could be the way you are setting your file´s location. Normally, I call the file from the project (it could be allocated in your computer or not). So, the idea is: src="../folder1/folder2/your_picture.png"

Comment: The source is this: file:///home/davide/Pictures/kurt1.jpg is it good? Cause it's still not working

Comment: try the url in this way.. 

src = "/Pictures/angle_olympics_croppedxcf.jpg" 

The leading  ( / )  will take you to the root of the project....

Instead Of ( "Pictures/angle_olympics_croppedxcf.jpg" )

Try this ( "/Pictures/angle_olympics_croppedxcf.jpg" )

Comment: Didn't work, I think the broswser have a problem in reading the image. Instead of it it shows the alt text. Damn it it's frustrating...What can I do?

Comment: need to know your folder structure....

Comment: file:///home/davide/Pictures/image.jpg

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/overhead-view-of-two-business-persons-in-the-lobby-picture-id520791880?s=2048x2048" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="http://media.istockphoto.com/photos/friends-connection-digital-devices-technology-network-concept-picture-id525208898?s=2048x2048" alt="Image">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>Lorem</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://codepen.io/ivinraj/pen/JWNKeL?editors=1100)

Comment: Hi there thank you for replying. I don't see any difference in the structure between my code and yours, to be honest. Maybe I am missing something?